# Full outer join implementation in MySQL 5.7+

Tags: mysql, join, mysql-5.7

I have a scenario with MySQL joins
Look at the 2 tables given below

### Table1:

```
id   A   B
1    10  25
2    13  24
3    15  20
```

### Table 2:

```
id   C   D
2    12  21
3    10  18
4    13  23
```

My problem is to join these tables in a which returns all the rows in both tables with corresponding values

### Table1 JOIN Table2:

```
id     A     B     C     D
1     10     25   null  null
2     13     24    12    21
3     15     20    10    18
4     null   null  13    23
```

I think we can implement this using full outer join.
But in MySQL 5.7+ full join is not supported.
I searched many similar questions. But all are saying about left and right join with union.
That solution wont help me, because i have totally 7 tables like this. I need to get all the data from each table in this way.
So if i use left and right join with union my query will become a huge query.
So is there any other way to get this ?

Comment: Why do you have 7 tables?

Answer (score -1):

Use left and rigt join with `UNION ALL`

```
select a.id,A,B, C, D
from table1 a left join table2 b n a.id=b.id
union 
select a.id,A,B, C, D
from table1 a right join table2 b n a.id=b.id
```

Comment: if there are a number of tables like this and i want to join all these tables in a similar way what will i do ?  If i use this left and right join with union all it will create a big query

Comment: Obviously, right JOIN is not actually required, but whatever floats your boat

Comment: This solution is wrong.